# We would like formatting for LOLCODE

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting

This question is a very good question about LOLCODE code:
[Down with FizzBuzz... LOL](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/61416/18427)

The formatting is pretty good except for the comments, which aren't formatted as comments.

I can see this being a popular formatting not only in Code Review but also in Programming Puzzles and Code Golf as well.

From looking at the [official site](http://lolcode.org/) it seems as though it is catching on much like Brainf*ck did.

Comment: And I thought you were joking...

Comment: @retailcoder: LOLNOPE

Comment: Syntax highlighting is an extension of [Google Prettify](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/), you should get support added that way.

Comment: I can second that. thank you @MartijnPieters